# Cannot instantiate class caused by InvocationTargetException and NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwGV0.png)    //Base class
    package com.IVAPP.qa.Base;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;



public class BaseClass {
public static Properties prop;
public static WebDriver driver;



public BaseClass() throws IOException{


    try{
    prop = new Properties();

    //prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Jomonli\\workspace\\IVAPP_Automation\\src\\main\\java\\com\\IVAPP\\qa\\Config\\Config.properties"));
    FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Jomonli\\workspace\\IVAPP_Automation\\src\\main\\java\\com\\IVAPP\\qa\\Config\\Config.properties"));
    prop.load(ip);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void intialization(){
//  String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
//
//  if(browserName.equals("IE")){
//      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\Jomonli\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
//     //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); }

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jomonli\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
     driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();


    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
}
}
```

## This is the base class which is extended to class which I'm trying to run.

```
LoginPageTest
package com.IVAPP.qa.OffShoreTestCases;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.IVAPP.qa.Base.BaseClass;
import com.IVAPP.qa.OffShorePage.HomePage;
import com.IVAPP.qa.OffShorePage.LoginPage;



public class LoginPageTest extends BaseClass {
    LoginPage loginpage;
    HomePage homePage;
    WebDriver driver;

public LoginPageTest() throws IOException{
    super();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws IOException{
    intialization();
//   String exePath = "C:\\Users\\Jomonli\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe";
//     //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
//     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);
//     driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    this.loginpage =new LoginPage();
    homePage = new HomePage();
}
@Test(description="Logging in with valid credentials")
public void LoginTest() throws IOException{
    homePage = loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("UserID"), prop.getProperty("Password"));
}
@AfterMethod
public void teardown(){
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

=================================================================================================
    Testng.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.IVAPP.qa.OffShoreTestCases.LoginPageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This is testng .xml and it points to right class which I'm trying to run, but it says it cannot instantiate the class. Does this have something to do with driver path.

## I tried Project>Clean>Update maven,Changed the path,wrote different code but Nothing worked

```
Exception errors
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.IVAPP.qa.OffShoreTestCases.LoginPageTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:373)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:285)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:104)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:90)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:422)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:252)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:222)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:171)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:28)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:604)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:170)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:117)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1359)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1346)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.IVAPP.qa.Base.BaseClass.<init>(BaseClass.java:28)
    at com.IVAPP.qa.OffShoreTestCases.LoginPageTest.<init>(LoginPageTest.java:23)
    ... 30 more
```

These are the two exception i m getting

Comment: Could you please paste your test class? have you initialized the driver?

Comment: Yes, i just added my testclass 'LoginPageTest'

Comment: really can't see the exception in the screenshot. It is always good to paste the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I added that as well to the post

Answer (score 0):

As you see the exception is appearing while trying to read the config file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
```

could you please make changes to the config path?

```
FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("Config/Config.properties");
prop.load(ip);
```